# Loading view on mouseover

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I made a module for loading a view with Drupal.ajax. This works perfect.

But is there an easy way to load the view on mouseover, and not on click?

This is the code:

```
<?php

function dynamic_regio_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['regio/ajax'] = array(
    'title' => 'Dynamic Regio',
    'page callback' => 'dynamic_regio_get_by_category_id',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function dynamic_regio_get_by_category_id($cat_id){
  $viewName = 'regio_submenu'; // The name of the view we are going to load

  $args = array($cat_id);  // Array of arguments we set for the view. Only one argument in our example. your actual view may require additional arguments which you may need to set
  $displayId = 'block'; // The display id of for the view. 

  // Call the views_embed_view function to returned themed view output
  $html = views_embed_view($viewName, $displayId, $args);

  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#dynamic_regio-wrapper', $html);

  $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($page);

  exit;
}

function dynamic_regio_theme() {
   return array(
      'dynamic_regio_javascript' => array(
         'arguments' => array(),
      ),
   );   
}

function dynamic_regio_init() {
  theme('dynamic_regio_javascript');
}

function theme_dynamic_regio_javascript() {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');  
}
```

Comment: Could you post the JS code you're using to invoke the click event on your link?

Comment: I make use of the "use-ajax" class. So my links look like this one: <a class="categoryLink use-ajax" href="/regio/ajax/20">Murcia</a>

Comment: That isn't functionality provided by Drupal core, are you using a contributed module that does add this functionality? Maybe CTools?

Comment: Ctools is installed yes... Do you have an idea what code I could use to load a view on mouseover?